# Android TextView below EditText disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

This is my XML file, which defines two `EditText` components and two `TextView` components, but when the second `EditText` component

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

fill up the whole screen, the two `TextView` components will disappear, why is this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/title_hint"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/titleColorHint"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@null"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/text_hint"
    android:layout_below="@id/note_title"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/textColorHint"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:background="@null"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/dotted_line"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:textColor="@color/dottedLineColor"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:text="Note date"
    android:textColor="@color/dateTextColor"
    android:textSize="11sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to fix the height if the multiline edit text or make the parent scroll view so that the screen is scrollable. The TextViews are getting pushed below the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all the EditText widgets in Android are multi-lined.

Here is some sample code:

```
  <EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it and It worked.Now there is another question: how to make the four components scroll together?Like the way google keep woks?